# File sequence > Find Name Pattern

Tags: c#, file, pattern-matching, sequence

I'm trying to figure out a solid way to solve multiple types of file sequences.

Consider these sequences

> file_0000.jpg
>   file_0001.jpg
>   file_0002.jpg etc
>   &
>   new1File001.jpg
>   new1File002.jpg
>   new1File003.jpg

So it needs to find out where the first decimal of the sequence code starts.

```
FileInfo[] files = new DirectoryInfo(@"\\fileserver\").GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
var grouped = files.OrderBy(f => f.Name).GroupBy(f => f.Name.Substring(0, f.Name.LastIndexOf("_")));
```

Obviously this finds file sequences where the sequence numbering is separated by "_". I want it to be filtered by the position of the first decimal of the last decimal sequence. My regex skills are not good and even then I don't know how to use it in the lamba expression.

The main question is, how can I find out where the **number string** starts for the above mentioned cases.

Any pointers would be great!
Thanks,
-Johan

Comment: I might be a idiot but I can't seem ti find the question.  What is it exactly that you are trying to do? Are you looking for a way to order the list?

Comment: I edited the post slightly, hopefully the last paragraph makes it more clear now. Thanks!

Comment: Am I understanding you correctly if I say that you want to find the position for each sequence of file names on which the number sequences start? So, for file_0000.jpg it would be 4 and for foo0000.jpg it would be 2?

Comment: @Banang : Exactly, but it should not be confused if an decimal number was found in the string, file1_new0000.jpg should return 9. It's easy for me to find a special character and use that, but I have to compensate for people forgetting a special character.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, regex is to rescue:

```
var r = new Regex(@".+(\d{2,}).");
var grouped = 
    files.
        OrderBy(f => f.Name).
        GroupBy(f => r.Match(f.Name).Groups[0].Value);
```

Comment: I think this is the right path to go, but the expression is not working out for me, it doesn't return the right value.

Comment: `var r = new Regex( @".+(\d{3,})", RegexOptions.RightToLeft );`
`var grouped = files.
                        OrderBy(f => f.Name).
                        GroupBy(f => f.Name.Substring(0, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f.Name).Length - r.Match(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f.Name)).Groups[1].Length));`

Is what I have now. It works, but it feels a bit slow. Any improvements that can be made? Thanks.